# ¿Cómo crear un treeView con boostrap 4?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html5, ajax, bootstrap

Hace cuatro horas estoy mirando la forma de crear esto. He encontrado varios ejemplos, pero muchos usan una versión de boostrap vieja y mi sistema está usando la versión 4.

Necesito crear como 5 niveles en una vista de árbol, estaría bueno que tuvieran iconos y enlaces ¿cuál es la forma más fácil de crear esto?. Muchos ejemplos están incompletos, no los puedo hacer andar.

Algunos enlaces que he visto:

https://mdbootstrap.com/plugins/jquery/treeview/

https://jonmiles.github.io/bootstrap-treeview/

https://www.creative-tim.com/product/black-dashboard?partner=114912

[https://www.jqueryscript.net/other/Folding-Tree-Structures-jQuery-fileexplore.html](https://www.jqueryscript.net/other/Folding-Tree-Structures-jQuery-file-explore.html)

https://www.webslesson.info/2017/05/make-treeview-using-bootstrap-treeview-ajax-jquery-with-php.html

https://www.phpflow.com/php/treeview-using-bootstrap-treeview-php-mysql/

Aspiro a conseguir algo similar a lo que se aprecia en esta imagen, pero con color de fondo verde y quizás sin bordes.

[image: imagen]

Les agradecería consejos de como hacer esto, por favor.

Comment: Deberías incluir el código de lo que has tratado de implementar!

Comment: He probado muchos códigos, incluso intenté probar uno tuyo: https://es.stackoverflow.com/posts/comments/528718?noredirect=1 pero no he podido instalarlo ¿me ayudarías?

Comment: ¿puedo iniciar un chat contigo?

Comment: Si sabes como hacerlo claro!

Comment: La única forma que conozco es que debes entrar al chat general y desde ahí selecciono para abrir un chat contigo. https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/30872/stack-overflow-en-espanol

Comment: Bueno, avisame cuando estes conectado.. yo estaré durante todo el día

Comment: Entro a la chat en 20 min

Comment: tengo algunos avances.. yo creo que, como te indique si quieres que estemos bien alineados deberiamos usar skype, de lo contrario no calzaremos nunca

Answer (score 1, accepted):

La solución sería, como te comente mediante Skype utilizar la librería de **[Gijgo](https://gijgo.com/tree/demos/bootstrap-treeview)** - o alguna similar -, la que soporta bootstrap 4.

El código sería

```js
$('#tree').tree({
  dataSource: [ 
    { 
      text: 'Planta 1', 
      children: [ 
        { text: 'Área 1', 
         children: [
           { text: 'Equipo 1',
             children: [
               { text: 'Punto 1' },
               { text: 'Punto 2' },
               { text: 'Punto 3' }
             ]
           }
         ] 
        } 
      ] 
    }
  ]
});
```

```html
<link href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/twitter-bootstrap/4.1.3/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
<link href="https://unpkg.com/gijgo@1.9.13/css/gijgo.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>

<div class="container">
  <div id="tree"></div>
</div>

<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.4.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://unpkg.com/gijgo@1.9.13/js/gijgo.min.js"></script>
```

Es una librería bastante completa, que tiene múltiples eventos y propiedades, dejo **[acá](https://gijgo.com/tree/configuration)** la documentación